# Approach for handling external REST API errors

Tags: java, go

We are dealing with external REST API. This API has more than 1200 possible error codes.
There are three projects who use this API. We want to make common error handling framework or library for this..
How can we handle external API errors? We would like to map these error codes to our company specific error description.

Comment: Use an API gateway or a load balancer from all 3 applications to call the external API. 
Handle the scenarios in gateway. 
This will help you to have common error handling besides other common things. 

Basically, the idea is to delegate every third party call to this new component i.e. gateway or load balancer.